# How can I localize a dynamic object?

Tags: objective-c, oop, localization

My app pulls some dynamic content localized in two languages from a server in JSON like so:

```
Banners: [
{
    BannerId: 1,
    Headline: {
        en: "English String",
        fr: "French String"
    }
}]
```

I want to create an object called Banner that has a property Headline, whose getter returns the localized version of the string, the same way NSLocalizedString would choose the correct string for static content.

Is it possible to use NSLocalizedString for this or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a class called NSLocalizedObject, which had a dictionary property that stores the data for both languages. I then created getters and setters which checked the current language the app is in and returns the data in the appropriate language. All of my data model classes that need to be localized inherit from this class.

```
-(NSObject *)getLocalizedObjectForProperty:(NSString *)property {
    NSDictionary *objs = [_propertyDictionary objectForKey:property];
    NSString *lang = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentLanguage"];


    return [objs objectForKey:lang];


}

-(NSObject *)getLocalizedObjectForProperty:(NSString *)property forLanguage:(NSString *)lang {
    NSDictionary *objs = [_propertyDictionary objectForKey:property];

    return [objs objectForKey:lang];


}
//takes a whole localized json style object - like {@"en":bleh, @"fr:bleh}
-(void)setLocalizedObject:(NSDictionary *)obj forProperty:(NSString *) property {
    [_propertyDictionary setObject:obj forKey:property];
}

//allows you to set an object for a specific language
-(void)setObject:(NSObject *)obj forProperty:(NSString *) property forLang:(NSString *)lang {

    //if a language isn't handed in then it means it should be set for the current language
    //applicable in the case where I want to save an image that is downloaded to the current language for that image.
    if (!lang) lang = DEFAULTS(@"currentLanguage");

    //get a mutable version of the dictionary for the property you want to set
    NSMutableDictionary *mutObjs = (NSMutableDictionary *)[_propertyDictionary objectForKey:property];

    //if the above call returns nil because the dictionary doesn't have that property yet then initialize the dictionary
    if (!mutObjs) {
        mutObjs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    //set the obj for the correct language
    [mutObjs setObject:obj forKey:lang];

    //store the property back into the propertyDictionary
    [_propertyDictionary setObject:(NSDictionary *)mutObjs forKey:property];

}
```

Note that you could check the actual language the OS is set to, but I have a requirement that the user can change the app's language despite the OS's current language.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `NSLocalizedString()` and all variants thereof work within your app bundle. You could, in theory, use them (more precisely, `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()`, if it was possible to serialize the contents of your object into a `.strings` file **inside the app bundle.** Unfortunately, the app bundle is not writable, so I'm pretty confident you can't use these <s>functions</s> macros.

What you can do is you obtain the current system language identifier, then you use it as an index into your deserialized dictionary:

```
NSString *curSysLang = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];
NSString *headline = jsonObject[0][@"Headline"][curSysLang];
```